# Problem running a sale on the site

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

Craft shows the sale running, and can tell which products are on sale using a:

```
{% set saleProducts = craft.products()
  .hasVariant({
    hasSales: true,
    hasStock: true
}).all() %}
```

loop, but on the product itself. However, `variant.onSale` doesn't detect the sale, and `variant.salePriceAsCurrency` brings up the original price.

In the CMS looks like things are set up correctly -- the sale is connected to the product/varient and the product is promotable.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share your ``for`` code that spits out the ``saleProducts``?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:
The discounted price will only be shown for the item already ADDED to the cart.

```
{% for lineItem in cart.lineItems %}
{{ dump(lineItem.total) }}
{% endfor %}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwsZa.png

https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-models-lineitem.html#public-properties

Therefore, I think you can get a [saleModel](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-elements-variant.html#sales) applicable to the iterable variant
and then use [these properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z760w.png) to manually calculate and display the discount

https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-models-sale.html#public-properties